# Unable to view log message in VS Output window using Nlogger for MSTest

Tags: c#, mstest, nlog

Using MSTest and NLogger i was able to write messages to log file but I don't see the messages any more in Output window of VS test explorer. Below is the configuration i'm using for NLogger. Any help?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="true"
      internalLogLevel="Trace" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">

  <variable name="brief" value="${longdate} | ${threadid} | ${level} | ${callsite} | ${message}"/>


  <targets>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="C:\Test.log" layout="${brief}"  />
    <target name="console" xsi:type="Console" />
    <target name="debugger" xsi:type="Debugger" layout="${logger}::${message}"/>

  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="debugger" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="console" />
 </rules>
</nlog>
```

Answer (score 0):

At Test Explorer Window, select your test and click in the Output link:

[image]

It'll open a new window with the console content

[image]